# How to handle Umbraco internal application call to a folder with IIS redirect

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

Umbraco version 7.4.3

I have an Umbraco website (internal) which is used for content management and previewing. A copy of this website (external) lives on another server and is used by the general public. The content changes are made internally, published to the internal site, and at the same time, published to the external site.

There is no need to provide access to the Umbraco backend of the external site, therefore, I have placed an IIS redirect on the "umbraco" folder to a 404 page. This works perfectly until a report is called on the external site.

The reports are displayed in the browser's PDF viewer using AngularJS and a call similar to {http}/umbraco/surface/PDFReport/GetDataExport

When calling a report the IIS redirect is actioned because the "umbraco" folder is being accessed; the PDF viewer shows the 404 page.

How can I block access to the "umbraco" folder except for calls to the surface controllers of the reports? Is another method of redirecting/routing required?

Please let me know if more details or code samples are required.

Regards,

Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about making a rewrite rule with an "exception"/negation for the specific path? [Exclude path in IIS rewrite rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574022/exclude-path-in-iis-rewrite-rule)

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply Jannik. A combination of this and the link provided by @muirisOG solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to answer Jannik as his solution worked for us, but I wasn't allowed.

Anyway, have a look here:

https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7/72207-disabling-access-to-umbraco-backoffice#comment-231849

Answer (score 0):

I believe this tutorial is what you are looking for:

http://www.jondjones.com/learn-umbraco-cms/umbraco-developers-guide/umbraco-troubleshooting/how-to-change-the-umbraco-7-admin-url

Works a treat!

Craig