# exclude a URL from rewrites

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I have a `nodejs` application running on `iis`.

I have url rewrite rule which sends all request to a custom `server.js` page.

I want to add a new rule or modify the existing one so that  a particular url `/something` reaches the iis and not the rule I have written.

My rule currently:

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="node">
                <match url="/*" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Please help on this one.

Comment: possible duplicate from this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574022/exclude-path-in-iis-rewrite-rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            <rule name="sendToNode">
                <match url="/*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="/something$" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
            </rule>
```